# What must be given in the loadurl() function for an application to run?

Tags: android

I created a basic phonegap project in android and the project to eclipse. I tried to run my project on my phone. 
My application was installed on my device but I was not able to run my application.

I believe its a problem with the `loadurl()` function.

```
loadurl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

what must be given in the `loadurl()` function so that my application runs and displays the page

Comment: Try using `super.loadurl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");`

Comment: I tried it but im still not able to run my application on my device

Comment: what must be given in the loadurl() function so as to run my application on the device?

Comment: You are passing the right parameter. There's probably something wrong with your code somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the WWW directory in uppercase letters? If yes, then you'll have to pass the uppercase form in your url

```
super.loadurl("file:///android_asset/WWW/index.html");
```